# Yii Widget, unexpected ), where is the error?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, widget

```
<?php 
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert', array(
      'block'=>true, // display a larger alert block?
      'fade'=>true, // use transitions?
      'closeText'=>'&times;', // close link text - if set to false, no close link is displayed
      'alerts'=>array( // configurations per alert type
        'success'=>array(
          'block'=>true,
          'fade'=>true,
          'closeText'=>'&times;',
        ), // success, info, warning, error or danger
      ),
    ),
  );
?>
```

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /dev/shm/untitled.php on line 14

I really can't find the error and watched it like 100 times. Need to implement this widget,
 thanks!

There are 4 opening parenthesis and 4 closing. Commas are ok, so... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert', array(
      'block'=>true,
      'fade'=>true,
      'closeText'=>'&times;',
      'alerts'=>array( 
        'success'=>array(
          'block'=>true,
          'fade'=>true,
          'closeText'=>'&times;'
        ),
      ),
    ), // you have comma here - it's mistake
  );
?>
```

Comment: Hmmmm sure, I don't know why I thought it was inside an array

Comment: NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 (Build 201210100934)

Answer (score 0):

see instruction

```
Requires

php: >=5.4.0
```